# How do I add minimize / maximize buttons to GNOME shell windows?

Tags: gnome-shell, window-buttons

Just installed Ubuntu 12.04, then I did

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

and windows have only a close button, how can I enable minimize / maximize? The old gconf-editor doesn't seem to work cause it has the three buttons in the config.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bring back minimize and maximize buttons in Gnome 3](http://askubuntu.com/questions/651347/how-to-bring-back-minimize-and-maximize-buttons-in-gnome-3)

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You need gnome tweak tool.

Click the Download button to install with Ubuntu Software Center:

[image: Install via the software center]

---

Or you can install in Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Then open Advanced Settings to change the minimize and maximize buttons.

Comment: Hmmm... could not find the specific option, I had to use ubuntu-tweak. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Rmano Shell > Arrangement of buttons on the titlebar [Close Only is the default setting]

Comment: FYI in Ubuntu 14.04 (Tweak Tool 3.10.4) the toggles to show Maximize and Minimize title bar buttons are in the Windows section

Comment: Why is this not default?

Answer (score 44):

Install `dconf-editor`:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
dconf-editor
```

Then navigate to:

```
org.gnome.shell.overrides >> button-layout
```

and set value to:

```
close,minimize,maximize: **OR** :maximize, minimize,close
```

Note that you might also perform this from console:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.overrides button-layout close,minimize,maximize:
```

In current versions of Gnome, you may need to use this instead:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout 'close,minimize,maximize:'
```

Comment: Well done vanlong.  Just to add this can be done from terminal too: `gsettings set org.gnome.shell.overrides button-layout close,minimize,maximize:`

Comment: thanks Todd, things worked quite good after using the tweak you mentioned. :)

Comment: the menu button on the window buttons is also available. I have my layout as `close,minimize,maximize:menu`

Comment: How do i disable it in terminal?

Comment: I had to navigate to org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences >> button-layout to get it to work w/ dconf-editor.

Answer (score 18):

This is very simple guys, just type the following command in the terminal, it worked for me:

```
gsettings set  org.gnome.shell.overrides button-layout ':minimize,maximize,close'
```

In Ubuntu 17.10 (and Debian 9 Stretch) with gnome 3.26.1 command is:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout ':minimize,maximize,close'
```

(thanks to [Ohto Nordberg's reply](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125765/how-do-i-add-minimize-maximize-buttons-to-gnome-shell-windows#comment1548832_299075)).

Comment: I feel this option is better than tweak-tool. It works for me. Thanks

Comment: This option is very cool

Comment: In Ubuntu 17.10 with gnome 3.26.1 command is 
gsettings set  org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences  button-layout ':minimize,maximize,close'

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem where my Ubuntu 12.04 windows only showed the close button. I realize that it is possible to right click on the menu bar to get the missing minimize and maximize functionality but I wanted the buttons back.

I was going to install Ubuntu Tweak but found the "Advanced Settings" application. I just went to the "Shell" tab and set "Arrangement of buttons on the titlebar" from "Close Only" to "All". This restored the missing buttons onto my windows.

I hope this alternate solution helps people with the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

I found [this page](http://alexsleat.co.uk/2012/04/11/ubuntu-12-04-moving-the-windows-buttons-back-to-the-right/) when I was looking for an answer to this question. Thought some people would appreciate this information.

Here is the terminal command for those that are two lazy to open a link. Just wanted to give credit to the original contributor of this information.

```
gconftool -s /apps/metacity/general/button_layout -t string menu:minimize,maximize,close
```

Comment: Re: links, people may not want to open links because they don't know what they land on.  For askubuntu/stackoverflow and others, links without info are bad because the link may break, and the answer isn't self-contained.

Answer (score 3):

For **Ubuntu 14.04+**, you might need to run the following:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings overrides "{'Gtk/DecorationLayout': <':minimize,maximize,close'>}"
```

Comment: Does it conflict with the gnome-tweaking-tool solution?

Answer (score 3):

On 12.04 and 14.04, the answer given by @user161127 worked well for me (entering the following in the terminal)

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.overrides button-layout ':minimize,maximize,close'
```

However, on 16.04, I needed to use the path given by @JivanAmara instead:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout ':minimize,maximize,close'
```

Answer (score 1):

Install ubuntu tweak.Open ubuntu tweak and go to Tweaks>Window and set "off" in Close button only . But I didn't like this type of solution though I'm sharing this solution.

Answer (score 1):

To maximise, you can instead double-click on the window frame with the left button. To minimise, single-click the middle button on the window frame.

Comment: Middle button click does not work for me to minimize.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this after installing Gnome 40 where I lost the Firefox Minimize and maximize buttons.  Up above, user wojox gave the command line tools for the Gnome Shell.  This was important because Tweaks no longer works.  In his/her answer, I failed to note the difference between the leading ':' and trailing ':' in the string.  The trailing ':' moves the buttons to the left side of the menubar and the leading ':' puts them on the right side.

The choice is yours.

The simple command line solution (take note of ':' placement):

*This gives right buttons*

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout ':minimize,maximize,close'
```

*This gives left buttons*

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout 'minimize,maximize,close:'
```

You can also use the dconf editor. Note that dconf-editor is now its own package and there is no dconf-tools.

Install dconf-editor:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
dconf-editor
```

Then navigate to:

org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences >> button-layout

and set value to:

close,minimize,maximize: **OR** :maximize, minimize,close

Comment: worked on redhat +1

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the buttons, you can still minimize/maximize windows by right-clicking on their titlebar and selecting the appropriate entry from the menu.

Answer (score 0):

In Gnome tweak tool --> click on Shell in left column and then in right column for Arrangement of buttons in title bar select "all", instead of"close only".

Answer (score 0):

The `dconf-tool` editor solutions described [by vanlong441](https://askubuntu.com/a/128755/22949) and [by Todd Partridge](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125765/how-do-i-add-minimize-maximize-buttons-to-gnome-shell-windows/177132#comment162216_128755) worked for me. The only thing to add is you can change the side of the buttons on the window by moving the `:` in the string, and change the order of the buttons by moving their names around. (Useful for personal preference and also pranking).

Comment: As you've posted this as a separate answer rather than a suggested edit (or comment), you may want to expand it further, giving explicit examples of how different strings (with the `:` in different places) produce different behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 use

```
dconf-editor
```

to open the Editor and you can find it here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in lubuntu to show minimize maximize buttons to title bar of windows

```
sudo apt install `dconf-editor`
dconf-editor
```

ctrl+L & type to path:

```
/org/gnome/desktop/wm/preferences/button-layout
```

then use default value on
and type `menu:minimize,maximize,spacer,close` to show minimize maximize buttons to windows

Answer (score -1):

To right align buttons, put the colon in the beginning:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.overrides button-layout :minimize,maximize,close
```