# No Minimize/Maximize buttons in Gnome 3

Tags: gnome, 14.04, nautilus

I have installed Ubuntu Gnome 14.04

The problem is :

Nautilus(I think it called "Files" in gnome-shell) has no Minimize/Maximize button !

I have enabled `gnome-tweak-tool -> Windows -> Maximized/Minimized`, but Nautilus has not Minimize/Maximize buttons!

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: did you follow this workaround http://askubuntu.com/questions/125765/how-do-i-add-minimize-maximize-buttons-to-gnome-shell-windows

Comment: Yes I did, but problem doesn't solved

Comment: I just logged into `Gnome-shell` using `dconf` as instructed in answer `2` works right away. Oh yeah, pardon, but you meant Nautilus also :-) let me check next

Comment: I exactly did instructed in answer 2 it works fine for all windows but nautilus !

Comment: maybe I'm blind but I don't see that option for `nautilus` maybe it's not possible at the moment, there's decoration for `nautilus` too as you can see in `org.gnome.nautilus` but I don't see option to edit with.

Comment: You can always press Alt+ Space to bring up window menu, and select minimize.

Answer (score 2):

hm... Actually there's an option for `minimize/maximize` it's kinda hidden, when you click on nautilus top panel you get:

[image]

I'll add more solutions, when/if I find.

Comment: I know that, not interesting...

Comment: oh :-) ok, I didn't know you already know that.

Comment: so, I did some deep research including Gnome official sources, and currently it's not possible to do with `Gnome 3.10+` only the way like on the screenshot, not even adding extensions will help you to add minimize/maximize buttons. Only if you install/replace to other file browser. I guess this be fixed but it's a question to Gnome developers.

Answer (score 1):

Solved mine with

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout ":minimize,maximize,close"
```

gsettings is a command line tool, by using it we are setting the property of desktop window manager's button layout to ":minimize,maximize,close" which will then have all three buttons instead of only close i.e a cross button

Comment: A little explanation would be useful. What does the command do, why it will work..etc.

Comment: Worked. Quick add: `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout` to show what you currently have

Answer (score 0):

So I just noticed that you used tweak tool but didn't notice you are asking about Nautilus. As far as I know after I did some research before that you can't do that. You can look on this [extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/18/native-window-placement/) or you can try [Nemo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nemo_%28file_manager%29). I personally use keyboard shortcuts to navigate.

Comment: `window placement` has nothing to do with `buttons`:-)

Comment: I use native windows placement plus keyboard shortcuts and I never felt like I need these buttons :p I already said with Nautilus it can't be done in Gnome 3 ;)

Comment: Apparently your research is 3 hours late than my answer :p

Answer (score 0):

Install Elementary theme (ftom Elementary OS). This will move close button to the left corner and appear maximize in right.

You will get like this:

[image]

But if you select other themes after Elementary theme, layout don't save and will back to default in the next log in. I think, it possible to copy layput settings from Elementary theme and put it in any other.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

On 20.04

Change or remove the shortcut for `settings`->`toggle maximization state`