# How to bring back minimize and maximize buttons in Gnome 3

Tags: gnome, customization, window, window-control

I have recently installed Ubuntu Gnome which has the latest version of Gnome 3 running on it, and I have noticed that on windows there are no minimize buttons, and no maximize buttons, although I can see that you do get the options if you do a right-click. I have already read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481728/no-minimize-maximize-buttons-in-gnome-3) question, and its answers, and have found that still none of them answer my question.

So my question is, as made clear in the title, how can I bring back the minimize and maximize buttons? Is this a bug? Or have Gnome decided not to have them?

---

**OS Information:**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid
```

Answer (score 176, accepted):

### The command line way

- add the values at the left side of `:` for buttons on the left side

  `close,minimize,maximize:`

  ```
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout "close,minimize,maximize:"
  ```

  [image]
- add the values at the right side of `:` for buttons on the right side

  `:minimize,maximize,close`

  ```
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout ":minimize,maximize,close"
  ```

  [image]
- or mix them

  `close:minimize,maximize`

  ```
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout "close:minimize,maximize"
  ```

  [image]

---

### The GUI way

Start the `gnome-tweak-tool`, open the <kbd>Windows</kbd> tab and switch the buttons for <kbd>Titlebar Buttons</kbd> in the right panel

[image]

[image]

Comment: But it doesn't seem to affect Nautilus, at least for me on 14.04.

Comment: OK. I don't know what that means in regard to your answer in relation to what I mentioned.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work anymore with Ubuntu 15.10

Comment: Works on Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 (obviously doesn't work on a stock install ofUbuntu 15.10, since Ubuntu switched to the Unity desktop). Thanks for the tip - have used Xubuntu and Ubuntu ... switched to Ubuntu Gnome, love it, but needed to know where to easily customize the desktop. Thanks!

Comment: This worked perfectly on Fedora 31.

Comment: Do I need to run this as my user?  (I presume so) Or is there a global setting I can do?

Comment: Works for me on Ubuntu 16.04 running GNOME 3.18.

Comment: If you dont find it under `Windows`, try `Window Titlebars`.

Answer (score 1):

It's in Tweaks -> Window Titlebars now (not Windows)

[image]