# How to customize the close/Min/Max options in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, customizer

I would like to keep close/Min/Max to my own way in Ubuntu 14.04.
Is there any way to customize it by software or via terminal?

Comment: The position of the buttons or the function?

Comment: Postion of the buttons #A.B

Comment: See my answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/651349/367165)

Comment: It has failed @ A.B

Comment: Ok, it's for GNOME.

Comment: i couldn't get you @A.B.

Comment: My answer is for  GNOME and not for Unity, sorry.

Comment: I think that it is not possible. See also: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-tweak-tool/+bug/1309942

Comment: May be you are right @lemonslice

Answer (score 0):

You could use Gnome Tweak Tools. Find it here

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-tweak-tool/

**Note** : You can only switch on/off visibility of maximize and minimize buttons.

Also, if you are interested, **Elementary OS(Freya)** has a custom tweak tool that allows you to specify **location and visibility** of max/min/close buttons from a **single line** in their tweak tool.

## **Update :**

Use ***dconf-editor***

- Access **dconf-editor** by pressing *Alt+F2* and type in
  *dconf-editor*
- In **dconf-editor** access *org*->*gnome*->*desktop*->*wm*->*preferences*
- In *preferences* change **button-layout** option like so -

> [option - will go on left side] : [option - will go on right
>   side],[option - will go on right side]

- options : minimize | maximize | close
- eg :

  > minimize,maximize:close

  buttons will appear as

> _ []                                                                                                                                                                  X