# xubuntu not showing minimize, maximize and close buttons

Tags: xubuntu, gnome-panel, appmenu, minimize, maximized

After latest update application window doesn't display minimize, maximize and close button

But it show minimize, maximize and close button when application is not maximized
[image]

I have installed gnome-tweak-tool but it display blank for title bar button

[image]

Comment: Is this true for all applications that are maximized, or just Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem this fixed it for me:

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout "close,minimize,maximize:"`

Comment: I run above command in terminal but nothing happen

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/174292/how-can-i-move-all-the-window-controls-to-the-right-or-left

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/651347/how-to-bring-back-minimize-and-maximize-buttons-in-gnome-3