# Two sets of titlebar buttons, where are they coming from?

Tags: gnome, 17.04, gnome-tweak-tool

Ubuntu 17.04 (regular version), I decided to try out the Gnome shell today by following [these instructions](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/05/install-gnome-3-20-ubuntu-16-04-lts).  This installed Gnome Shell 3.24 for me.

Now I noticed I have two sets of minimise/maximise buttons in the window titlebars.  Where are they coming from?

I know the right-side buttons come from the Windows settings in the Gnome Tweak Tool.  But the left side? I tried changing GTK+ theme, Shell Theme, no difference.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This question might help you](https://askubuntu.com/questions/651347/how-to-bring-back-minimize-and-maximize-buttons-in-gnome-3).

Your current button layout appears to be `"close,minimize,maximize:minimize,maximize"`.

To get the default itlebar button layout for GNOME you could try the Terminal command below:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout ":close"
```

Comment: Perfect, that was it - I looked in dconf-editor and my /org/gnome/desktop/wm/preferences/button-layout was `close,minimize,maximize:,minimize,maximize`.  I will play around with this