# Window title bars not showing window controls(close, minimize and maximize buttons) on certain applications

Tags: 22.10, android-studio, 23.04, window-buttons

I am currently using Ubuntu 23.04 but I am experiencing this issue from the time when I was using ubuntu 22.10.

Applications including Settings, Nautilus(Files), Nemo(Files) and LibreOffice does not show close, minimize and maximize buttons.

Other applications like Gnome Nibbles and Gnome Tweaks does show those buttons.

Well, it is an issue of buttons not visible rather than they are absent, because when I click on their approximate locations, those actions are being executed.

I have tried creating a new user and checked whether the issue persists, and the issue was not there, i.e, I could see those buttons, which may point out that it is a problem with user-specific configuration.

I don't know about causation, but I started experiencing this problem when I installed Android Studio on my system (from developers.google.com).

I have tried disabling all gnome-shell-extensions and rebooting, but the issue still persists.

I am using Nemo as the default file manager, but not sure whether it is a significant point here.

On nautilus, the hamburger menu is visible leaving some space for those buttons.

I tried changing the themes through Gnome Tweaks and restarting the shell, but the issue persists across all the themes.

I have no custom themes or "User themes" for Gnome-shell installed.

Devise specifications:
[image: Screenshot from settings => About].

I tried `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` but with no luck.

Please help me. I am facing this issue for quite a while.

Comment: Please let me know in the comments if any required detail is missing on my question.

Comment: Maybe some files in your $HOME does not belong to your user. Please diff concerned user and new user. `find $HOME -not -user $USER`

Comment: Please check https://askubuntu.com/questions/651347/how-to-bring-back-minimize-and-maximize-buttons-in-gnome-3

Comment: @nobody please see my edit. I am not familiar with diff command so please feel free to correct me. Also I already tried the answer of the question you commented but doesn't help. Thanks anyway.

Comment: ` I am using Nemo as the default file manager, but not sure whether it is a significant point here.` . You could have broken the desktop, indeed.

Comment: Temporarily create a new user, see if the issue persists there. If yes, then video driver issues (nvidia card) could be a possibility.

Comment: Sorry I meant you should compare the output from my find command. You can also try to reset the whole desktop. https://askubuntu.com/questions/56313/how-do-i-reset-gnome-to-the-defaults

Comment: @nobody Sorry, I tried resetting the GNOME to defaults, but still the problem is not solved. (I had backed up config anyway)

Comment: Sorry no idea any more.