Window titlebar buttons not displaying
I'm experiencing an issue with my Ubuntu setup where the close, minimize, and maximize buttons on window titlebars are not displaying icons, despite being functional (clickable). This problem occurred after attempting to change my cursor theme, which caused GNOME to crash and refuse to boot. To resolve the booting issue, I used "dconf reset -f /", which caused the problem that I described.
Here are the steps I've already tried without success:

Gnome-Tweaks with Maximize/Minimize buttons
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout 'close,minimize,maximize:'
Settings -> Default theme, User Theme

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)
Edit#1:

To change the cursor, I went to GNOME Tweaks - Appearance- Cursor and changed to DMZ-Black if I remember correctly.
I created a new user, the titlebar is working and displaying correctly for that user, so it doesn't seem to be a system file issue.
Tried loading the dconf file from the new "test" user since it was working over there but it didn't work. I'm not sure what the 'dconf reset -f /' broke at this point...

Edit #2

After loading the dconf file from the new temp user, SOME applications display the title bar and some don't.

Edit #3

Finally fixed the problem! I had to delete  ~/.config/gtk-4.0 and ~/.config/gtk-3.0, reboot, and now problem's gone! :)


This may help https://askubuntu.com/questions/651347/how-to-bring-back-minimize-and-maximize-buttons-in-gnome-3


What procedure did you follow to change the cursor theme? 2) Temporarily create a new user and log in there. If the issue also occurs there, then you know the problem is at the level of the system files. Test, and then use "edit" to add any relevant information to your question.


I created a new user and the titlebar buttons are displaying correctly. Would it be possible to cp the settings over to my home directory?
