# How to close, minimize, and maximize a specified window from Terminal?

Tags: gnome, window-manager, window, window-control

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18 and I am wondering if there is a way from Terminal to close, minimize, unminimize, maximize, and unmaximize specified windows?

Note - I've looked at [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125765/how-do-i-add-minimize-maximize-buttons-to-gnome-shell-windows) - I am asking how to do it from Terminal... Not how to add the buttons... The buttons are already there, I don't need to add them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I minimize a window from the command line?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4876/can-i-minimize-a-window-from-the-command-line)

Comment: @Anastasia: How is this a duplicate of that? That only asks about minimizing... I'm asking about all of the other stuff as well which is not answered there.

Comment: I assumed those actions are so closely related that answering one should lead to all the others, but you're right, that may be a broad sweep.

Now I'm also wondering in subsets of questions can be considered duplicates.

Comment: @Anastasia: Well, because the answers to the other question don't actually mention how to achieve this, even if they would help me, it is still not a duplicate of that question. Plus even if the answers to the other question answer my question, my question still isn't asking the same thing as the other one is asking.

Comment: Hi Para, I hope the question is still "open". An overview...

Comment: What's your main objective  ? perform any of the three actions on a window that you can select with cursor  ?

Comment: Would it be accepteable to have 3 keyboard shortcuts for active (currently focused) window ?

Comment: @Serg: Preferably I would like to be able to execute 5 commands in Terminal (each would do one of these things for the target window close, minimize, unminimize, maximize, or unmaximize). I would be able to either specify the current window (the Terminal window), or I would be able to somehow specify another window to do the actions on.

Comment: OK.  I'm gonna cook up a few things , will post later today or tomorrow.  I've a few things put together already, but it will require time.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy: How's the cooking going? Or did you eat the pie before thinking of us? ;)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There are two important tools to manipulate windows from `cli`; `xdotool` and `wmctrl`. Both tools overlap each other in functionality, but the most important commands referring to your question:

In an (no doubt incomplete) overview, listing the commands I use most:

#### Closing a window

*wmctrl:*

```
wmctrl -ic <window_id>
```

#### Minimizing a window

*xdotool:*

```
xdotool windowminimize <window_id>
```

#### Un- minimizing a window

*wmctrl:*

*effectively* un- minimizing is done by:

```
wmctrl -ia <window_id>
```

I mention *effectively*, since the command moves to the corresponding desktop, unminimizes and raises the window, but the command *also* does that on windows which are not minimized.

#### Maximizing a window

*xdotool:*

```
xdotool windowsize <window_id> 100% 100%
```

*wmctrl:*

```
wmctrl -ir <window_id> -b add,maximized_vert,maximized_horz
```

#### Un- maximizing a window:

```
wmctrl -ir <window_id> -b remove,maximized_vert,maximized_horz
```

#### Notes

- Both `xdotool` and `wmctrl` are not on your system by default:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install xdotool wmctrl
  ```
- To run any of the commands on the currently *active* window:

  - for `wmctrl` commands, remove the `-i` option, replace `<window_id>` by `:ACTIVE:`
  - for `xdotool` commands: replace `<window_id>` by `$(xdotool getactivewindow)`
- In many cases, commands can be run by using either the *window id* or the *window name*. The `-i` option in `wmctrl` tells `wmctrl` to use the window id. I'd suggest *not* using the window's name as an identifier, to prevent name clashes. It happens more easily then you'd expect.
- From my own experience, using maximizing in a script; 
  Using `wmctrl` to maximize / unmaximize can be a bit buggy on both `Unity` and `Gnome`, while the `xdotool` option works more robust in my experience. 
  In most scripts, I end up in using a mix of both `wmctrl` and `xdotool`.

More info on [man wmctrl](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wmctrl) and [man xdotool](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/xdotool.1.html) (mainly the section: **WINDOW COMMANDS**).

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! But how do you also unminimize a window?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda see my updated answer :)

Comment: `wmctrl -ir <window_id> -b remove,maximized_vert,maximized_horz` not work on gnome 3.20

Comment: The xdotool minimize command didn't work for me. I found the command "`xdotool getactivewindow windowminimize`" worked though. I found that command [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4876/can-i-minimize-a-window-from-the-command-line)

Comment: Completely failed to specify how to even get window id

Answer (score 6):

Adding to Jacob Vlijm's answer:

```
xdotool windowactivate $minwinid
xdotool windowraise $minwinid
xdotool windowfocus $minwinid
```

Also works for unminimizing a window. The animation is faster for me.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Jacob Vlijm's answer:

Minimizing a window w/ xdotool by window name:

```
xdotool search -name '<window_name>' windowminimize
```

To get list of windows names use:

```
wmctrl -l
```

Answer (score -1):

To hide the current window:

```
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b toggle,hidden
```

Comment: Does not do anything at my side.  Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS default install.

Comment: @Tino, I'm also running 22.04 LTS, but I use Xfce window manager. I don't think that makes a difference, but I did have to install wmctrl. 'sudo apt-get install wmctrl'