# Bring application that has been closed (hidden) to front

Tags: gnome-shell, system-tray, electron

As [Electron based apps have trouble using the "systray"/tray icons](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/10427) in Gnome, closing (pressing X) on such applications lead effectively to them being hidden, as they also disappear from the application bar (? not sure about that term).

That means opening the app again would open a second (or third or ...) instance, which could cause errors to start appearing.

These apps show when doing  `ps -ef | grep my-app`, but is there any way of getting Gnome to render the window of an app that has been "closed"/hidden from view by sending it some signal?

**P.S. I know one can use `xdotool` or `wmctrl` to send X signals** ([see this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/703628/how-to-close-minimize-and-maximize-a-specified-window-from-terminal) link), but sending them to a window that has been removed by itself only results in error messages (since the window no longer exists).

Comment: Have you tried installing [TopIcons Plus](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1031/topicons/) extension? That might help showing the tray icon.

Comment: @pomsky That's an answer for a different question :-) I already have a "fix" for that, which is to prepend XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity to the command that is being invoked. That hack works fine (most of the time).