# How to determine if window is maximised or minimised from bash script

Tags: command-line, window-manager, xdotool, wmctrl, xprop

I have a bash script that moves my windows from the left screen to right screen in dual-screen setup. Currently the way it works is cycling through the window ids that are given by `xdotool search --onlyvisible --maxdepth 2 --class ""` and then moves them to the right by the screen width. It already works... unless the window in question is maximises or minimised.

So what is needed is a way to check the current status of the window. I have found [an answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/703628/how-to-close-minimize-and-maximize-a-specified-window-from-terminal) that provides the way to add and remove those bits, but where is the way to check if they are set already?

If it is not possible to do via **xdotool**, it should be possible to reuse the window id provided by the command mentioned above.

Comment: you can also look at [`devilspie`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Devilspie) which is designed to do exactly this kind of window work. So no need to recode, just configure

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Retrieve info on the window state

You can get the info (and a lot more) from the command:

```
xprop -id <window_id>
```

To get what you are specifically looking for:

```
xprop -id 0x04c00010 | grep "_NET_WM_STATE(ATOM)"
```

The output will look like:

```
_NET_WM_STATE(ATOM) = _NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_HORZ, _NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_VERT, _NET_WM_STATE_HIDDEN
```

on a window that is maximized (h + v) and minimized at the same time, or just

```
_NET_WM_STATE(ATOM) =
```

(or no output at all) if none of those is the case.

#### More fun

Of course, using various languages, you can use [Wnck](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Wnck-3.0/classes/Window.html), like in the python snippet below. (snippet from [window-shuffler](https://github.com/UbuntuBudgie/window-shuffler/blob/master/shuffler_geo.py)). The snippet outputs a list, showing the window name + either `True` or `False` (minimized).

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import gi
gi.require_version('Wnck', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Wnck


def get_winlist(scr=None, selecttype=None):
    """
    get the window list. possible args: screen, select_type, in case it is
    already fetched elsewhere. select type is optional, to fetch only
    specific window types.
    """
    if not scr:
        scr = Wnck.Screen.get_default()
        scr.force_update()
    windows = scr.get_windows()
    if selecttype:
        windows = [w for w in windows if check_windowtype(w, selecttype)]
    return windows

wlist = get_winlist()
for w in wlist:
    print(w.get_name(), ",", w.is_maximized())
```

Output looks like:

```
Wnck.Window - Classes - Wnck 3.0 - Mozilla Firefox , True
Postvak IN - vlijm@planet.nl - Mozilla Thunderbird , True
Showtime , False
settingsexample.vala - Visual Studio Code , False
*Niet-opgeslagen document 1 - gedit , False
desktop_weather , False
Tilix: Standaard , False
```

#### N.B.

- `xprop` will handel both hex (as output from e.g. `wmctrl`) and decimal (as output from e.g. `xdotool`) id's equally e.g. either use:

  ```
  xprop -id 111371626
  ```

  or

  ```
  xprop -id 0x06a3656a
  ```
- Methods will not work on Wayland!

Comment: Excellent suggestion +1.  As a comment, I tried it (under Linux, X11) and got slightly different results.  When a window is neither hidden nor maximized, `_NET_WM_STATE(ATOM)` does not, as shown in the answer, appear with an empty value.  Instead, it is not in the output at all.

Comment: @John1024 Ah, thanks! will add it to the answer.

Comment: On my system it is shown in either case, even when empty.

Comment: I want to add that window id can be given as a cecimal number, so no need to convert to hex. Just in case this will help somebody.

Comment: @v010dya Thanks! See updated answer.