# Where is The Minimize button script?

Tags: bash, gui, window, background-process

I'm trying to write a script to make my OS faster so I decided to limit CPU for background apps and minimized windows.
There could be so many different ways to do that and I know two of them:

1. Write the bash script that looks forward to the status of the windows.
2. Add the CPU-Limiter bash script to minimize button script

These are the ways I could think of and if I wanna go into one of these two ways I ask these questions:

1-Where is the directory of minimize button script?
2-Where is the source of windows and background apps' status?
If there is another way except for these ways, I pleased to hear it.

Comment: This are two questions and both have answers here: [Get window state](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1132023/how-to-determine-if-window-is-maximised-or-minimised-from-bash-script) and [Limit Resources of process](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045076/how-to-limit-resource-usage-for-a-given-process)

Comment: I hace used nice command to limit cpu on a process - renice -n -12 <pid>  - and as pid changes you can use , for recoll for eg, renice -n 10 $(pidof recoll)