# Start Visual Studio Code maximized from Bash

Tags: command-line, visual-studio-code

I am working on a project consisting of several components, which are separately opened in different Visual Studio Code instances, running on different displays.
In order to set everything up more quickly on a day-to-day basis, I wrote a very small bash script, initializing all instances. The script contains multiple lines like this:

```
code <folder-path> --new-window
```

However, windows created this way have to be maximized manually, an effort, which I would also like to automatize.
Is there any way to start a new Visual Code instance from terminal with a maximized window?
I already checked the help-options, but there doesn't seem to be dedicated options for displaying the window.

Comment: @Community What's hard to understand? How do you launch VS Code as maximised?

Comment: get some ideas @ `https://github.com/jc00ke/move-to-next-monitor/blob/master/move-to-next-monitor` . You will find a lot on SE too, when you know some of the tools to use/search for eg. wmctrl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the setting `window.newWindowDimensions` in Visual Studio Code to `maximized` worked for my case.
For more complex cases and moving windows to different displays, I would suggest [Wnck](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Wnck-3.0/index.html) as described in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1132023/how-to-determine-if-window-is-maximised-or-minimised-from-bash-script) answer.

Comment: Thanks. exact setting I was looking for.